# jar does not generate correct manifest file

Tags: java, scala, jar, executable-jar

I've test simple scala program and compiled it with scalac

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("hongseok yoon")
  }
}
```

If I run that 'java -cp .;scala-library.jar Test' and it works okay.
YES, scala-library.jar filee is in same directory.

This is my manifest file manifest.txt

```
Class-Path: scala-library.jar
Main-Class: Test
```

and I make jar with '**jar cfm Test.jar manifest.txt *.class**'

If I unzip generated Test.jar file and open manifest file, it does not contain Main-Class field. So, It cannot be run with '**java -jar Test.jar**'

I can edit it manually and Test.jar runs well.

**Why does jar miss Main-Class field? and how to fix this?**
(If I switch order of fields, only first field is shown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ONE more empty line** is needed **at the end of manifest file**.
What a stupid restriction! :(